# Gzip/TAR libraries for Javascript

Tags: javascript, gzip, tar

I would like to know this please, I am aware of some libraries that will access zip files but I would like to do this with tar files.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this article [Parsing tarballs with JavaScript](http://fhtr.blogspot.com/2010/05/parsing-tarballs-with-javascript.html)