# Add blob to tar and stream to server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stream, zip, tar, gzip

I have a server which only accepts .tar.gz files or .zip files.

Client side (in browser) I have a couple of Blob's in memory which I need to push back to the server.

Is there any way I can archive these Blob's (i.e. adding to zip or tar.gz) file by streaming them directly to the server?

I would like to avoid having the complete tar.gz file in memory before pushing back to the server.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a [duplicate question, see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930353/gzip-tar-libraries-for-javascript)

It links [to this article](http://fhtr.blogspot.com/2010/05/parsing-tarballs-with-javascript.html)

For streaming [tar files, see here.](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream)

Comment: Yes I saw that one, but it does not tell me how to create the tar or push the tar archive directly to server, without having the tar in memory completely.

Comment: OK, check my edit, there is a link to a streaming tar javascript library.

Comment: thx. It seems to be a node module and working with node streams. I don't feel confident enough to do a client side port...

Comment: no worries. Would it be possible to remove the 'duplicate question' remark, because I don't consider this as one, and when people see the question and see this as the first answer, I don't expect to have much success

Comment: I don't understand why you don't consider it to be a dupe?  Both are asking for tar libraries???